# activerecord: update object attribute without using transaction

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

Here is my code:

```
class UserTopicVisit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic

  def self.log_last_user_topic_visit(user_id, topic_id)
    visit = UserTopicVisit.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_topic_id(user_id, topic_id)
    visit.update_attributes!(:last_visit => Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db))
  end
end
```

Which is self-explainig.

The problems is: I need to be able to update object attribute without transaction, by simple mysql query. How can I accomplish that using activerecord?

Comment: I don't get it, if you don't want transactions, you can make "commit" after each query or change the tables engine to MyISAM

Comment: I want to have INNODB engine, but I don't need transaction in that separate case, just simple update query will be enough.

Comment: try writing "commit;" after each query that would be enough to save the changes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [update-column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column)

> Updates a single attribute of an object, without calling save
>
> - Validation is skipped.
> - Callbacks are skipped.
> - updated_at/updated_on column is not updated if that column is available.

Answer (score 0):

`update_attributes` uses a transaction, but oddly, `save` doesn't, so if you want callbacks and all that jazz without the transaction you can do:

```
visit.last_visit = Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db)
visit.save!
```

Under the hood, `update_attributes` actually just calls `attributes=` and then `save`.